# Sharding a large table using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a large MySQL table which I want to split into smaller tables. After the change I am planning to have a fixed (relatively small) number of smaller tables sharded based on the hash value of one of the columns. All my new tables will be on the same database.

My application is using SQLAlchemy (actually flask-sqlalchemy) to work with that table and I am looking for a way to re-write my code with minimal changes once that big table is split into smaller tables.

My current model class looks something like this (declarative style):

```
class SomeModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'some_models'
    ....
```

with `SomeModel` being referenced all over my code.

I am not sure what's the best way to represent my new state so my changes to the existing code are minimal.

Thanks.